# how to hide original image path using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to hide the original image path from my WordPress site. wherever it does not work. but other rules are work properly.

I had tried like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^unisol/([^/]+)$ ScanSource/$1 [L]
```

but it is not working.

when I check on .htaccess checker it shows true.

I need image path like bellow

Original Path: https://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/ScanSource/samsung-domecameras

Expected Path: https://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/unisol/samsung-domecameras

Images come from another domain.

Also, tell if there is a way other than .htaccess

I know this question asked before but it does not help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule on top of your s7d9.scene7.com .htaccess file for rewrites /is/image/unisol/any to /is/image/ScanSource/any

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^is\/image\/unisol\/(.*)$ /is/image/ScanSource/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `s7d9.scene7.com` domain is not accessible to me. I have another domain where I access this domain's images.

Comment: Using .htaccess file in this case is not possible to rewrite without access to s7d9.scene7.com (original and expected domain).

Comment: Is there another way?